# why my search in javascript is not working

Tags: javascript, html, search, input

Hi I try create form with input text and selected like below

This code works but not properly and I have wired problem (I think.) When the user does not type anything and clicks on enter, the form jumps to another input field. Also the search part and the enter prevent section not working until user types at least 2 character or types 1 or 2 character remove it and types it again. Why do these 2 problems happen and how to fix this?

I want when user type something in the text field check the selected option input and filter it base on the user text. and also prevent user from click on enter. for this I write this JavaScript code: (I have tree text field for search and 3 different selected input type. )

```js
function searchProduct(dropDownName, searchInputText) {
  const dropdown = document.getElementById(dropDownName);
  const input = document.getElementById(searchInputText);

  input.addEventListener("keydown", (event) => {
    if (event.key === "Enter") {
      event.preventDefault();
      input.focus();
    }
  });

  input.addEventListener("input", () => {
    const selectedOption = dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex];
    const searchTerm = input.value.toLowerCase();
    for (let i = 0; i < dropdown.options.length; i++) {
      const optionText = dropdown.options[i].textContent.toLowerCase();
      if (optionText.includes(searchTerm)) {
        dropdown.options[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        dropdown.options[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }
    if (event.key === "Enter") {
      event.preventDefault();
      input.focus();
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<input onchange="searchProduct('dropdowntype1','search1')" type="text" class="form-control rounded-0 border-0 border-bottom border-bottom-2 border-dark w-50" id="search1" placeholder="search">
<select asp-for="Related1" class="custom-select mt-3 w-50" id="dropdowntype1" name="Related1">
  <option> select one option </option>
  <option value="1">item 1</option>
  <option value="2">product2</option>
  <option value="3">item 3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: You shouldn't add an event listener inside the `onchange` function. Every time you change the input you'll add another event listener, without removing the previous one. Just add the event listeners once.

Comment: thank you my problem is solved. I remove the add listener and keep the body. also create 3 add listener outside of the on change for prevent enter on the my 3 text field and everything solved now.

Comment: Wrap in a form and use the submit event